# ¿como llevo a la izquierda el formulario de mi pagina web?

Tags: css, xhtml

en la parte de arriba de mi web, esta una imagen de inicio y un registro para usuarios, lo que deseo es que a la izquierda aparezca la imagen y a la derecha el registro pero me sale una debo de otra, mi codigo es este:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//w3c//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3c.org/TR/xhtml11-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta name="language" content="es" />
<meta name="revisit-after" content="15" />
<meta name="rating" content="general" />
<meta name="robot" content="index, follow" />
<meta name="owner" content="primate" />
<title> ejemplo 1 </title>
</head>
<body> 
<img src="14705783_357963464544311_5619060761625284588_n.jpg" height="200" width="200" title="inicio"/>
<style type="text/css">
form {text-align:right;}
legend {text-align:right;}
</style>
<form>  </br>
<fieldset> 
 <legend> Identificacion: </legend>
<label for="Nombre de usuario"> Nombre de usuario </label> </br>
<input type="text" name="Nombre de usuario" id="Nombre de usuario" size="25"  maxlength="20"/> </br>
<label for="Contraseña"> Contraseña </label> </br>
<input type="password" name="Contraseña" id="Contraseña" size="25"  maxlength="20"/> </br>
<input type="submit" name="ingresar" value="ingresar" />
</fieldset> </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

pero al insertar este codigo me sale uno debajo de otro y, ademas una parte del formulario sale a la derecha y otra a la izquierda

Answer (score 1):

Si comprendo bien, el problema es que quieres que imagen y formulario aparezcan al mismo nivel (uno al lado del otro), en lugar de uno sobre el otro. Entonces lo que necesitas hacer es que la imagen flote hacia la izquierda, y el formulario automáticamente ocupará la parte de la derecha de la imagen.

```
img[title=inicio] { float:left; }
```

Ahora, para que el contenido del formulario se muestre a la izquierda, sólo tendrías que quitar los `text-align:right` que pusiste para su contenido. El resultado sería algo como esto (ya de paso, he cambiado los `</br>` por el correcto `<br/>`):

```html
<img src="14705783_357963464544311_5619060761625284588_n.jpg" height="200" width="200" title="inicio"/>
<style type="text/css">
  img[title=inicio] { float:left; }
</style>
<form>  <br/>
  <fieldset> 
    <legend> Identificacion: </legend>
    <label for="Nombre de usuario"> Nombre de usuario </label> <br/>
    <input type="text" name="Nombre de usuario" id="Nombre de usuario" size="25"  maxlength="20"/> <br/>
    <label for="Contraseña"> Contraseña </label> <br/>
    <input type="password" name="Contraseña" id="Contraseña" size="25"  maxlength="20"/> <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="ingresar" value="ingresar" />
  </fieldset> 
</form>
```